# how to save dynamic check box changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, event-handling

I have few check boxes that are created dynamically and existing selections will be shown but when user makes changes I want to store them back. here is the code that generates and selects dynamically

```
private void Role(string role)
{
   SystemUserDal dal = new SystemUserDal();
   var userId = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
   var roles = dal.GetRolesList(userId);
   foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, string> r in roles)
   {
       CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
       chk.ID = r.Value;
       chk.Text = r.Value;
       if (role.Contains(r.Value))
       {
          chk.Checked = true;
       } 
       rolepanel.Controls.Add(chk);
   }
}
```

I am trying the following

```
private void GetCheckBoxes()
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in rolepanel.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox c = ctrl as CheckBox;
        string id = c.ID;
        string role = c.Text;
    }
}
```

when i step through the code it hits foreach loop with a count of 3, but the ctl is null. any clues?

Comment: What is `rolepanel`'s type?

Comment: its asp panel where the dynamic check boxes load

Comment: programmer93 its asp panel where dynamic checkboxes will b loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting the error because `rolepanel.FiondControl("chk")` returned `null` because it didn't find a control with `ID="chk"`. Method `FindControl` takes a string - an ID of the control you're looking for. The checkboxes you added don't have `ID="chk"`, they all have `ID=r.value` from your code. I would suggest to come up with some schema for IDs that you can use later to find the checkboxes.

If your `rolepanel` only contains your dynamically added checkboxes, you can just use `rolepanel.Controls` to get all of them.

Don't forget to cast controls to `CheckBox`.

So your `GetCheckBoxes()` could look something like:

```
private void GetCheckBoxes()
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in rolepanel.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox c = ctrl as CheckBox;
            string cText = c.Text;

            // do what you need to do with cText, or checkbox c
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Floremin I tried this, so i am trying to save the role to the user if a checkbox is checked so how can i get text of the check boxes checked?

Comment: Simply cast `ctrl` as `CheckBox` and then you can access all of it's properties normally. I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you Floremin. My role panel only contains dynamic check boxes but when i try the above code its not entering the if loop.

Comment: If it's not entering the look that means there are no controls in the `rolepanel`. When, in the page lifecycle are you calling `GetCheckBoxes`? Are you sure that checkboxes are added at that point, or you are re-loading everything? Describe your process a bit.

Comment: Floremin, there is a save button when its clicked it calls for a method that loads all the data into user there to load roles of the user i am calling GetCheckBoxes

Comment: Still can't figure out your workflow. It looks like you are resetting all the data and checkboxes are not there. Try stepping through the code and inspect values of relevant variables as you go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28476/discussion-between-user2167089-and-floremin)

Answer (score 2):

Does it still error if you cast it?

e.g.

```
private void GetCheckBoxes()
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rolepanel.FindControl("chk");
    if(chk!= null)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should cast control to CheckBox:

```
private void GetCheckBoxes()
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rolepanel.FindControl("chk");
    if(chk!= null)
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create public handler for CheckBox.CheckedChanged. Then all your dynamic CheckBoxes CheckedChanged event will be bind to that handler.

```
public void Checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender is CheckBox;
    if(checkbox!=null)
    {
         //do your saving things.
    }
}
```

Comment: event doesnt get rised when checkbox is checked or unchecked

Comment: google it why it is not raised. There are plenty of info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CheckBoxList and then doing something like this

```
        for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkList.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                // Store Item
            }
        }
```